# Return multiple columns in dplyr mutate

Tags: r, dplyr

How can I use `mutate` to apply a function to a column when the function returns multiple columns? Below I am trying to make dummy/one-hot columns from a character column (I know there are likely 100+ ways to make dummy columns but this is to illustrate the point of returning multiple columns).  It returns the dollar signs (e.g., `Treatment$Isnonchilled` instead of just `nonchilled`as shown in the image below.  This means the column is not an atomic vector but a data frame.

#### MWE

```
library(textshape)
library(dplyr)

one_hot <- function(x, drop.jth = TRUE, keep.na = TRUE, prefix = "Is", ...) {
    y <- tibble::as_tibble(textshape::mtabulate(x))
    if (keep.na) y[is.na(x), ] <- NA
    if(drop.jth) y <- y[1:(ncol(y) - 1)]
    colnames(y) <- paste0(prefix, colnames(y))
    y
}

CO2 %>%
    as_tibble() %>%
    mutate(
        conc2 = conc^2,
        across(c(Treatment), one_hot)
    )
```

#### Shows the column is not an atomic vector as desired but a data.frame

```
CO2 %>%
    as_tibble() %>%
    mutate(
        conc2 = conc^2,
        across(c(Treatment), one_hot)
    ) %>%
    lapply(class)

$Plant
[1] "ordered" "factor" 

$Type
[1] "factor"

$Treatment
[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"

$conc
[1] "numeric"

$uptake
[1] "numeric"

$conc2
[1] "numeric"
```

[image]

Comment: It would be more helpful if you could provide a reprex with some data, current output of your attempt and then a desired output.

Comment: The MWE does have some data (`CO2` is a built in data set )  The current output is an image.  I added additional code to show it's returning a data.frame column when I want it to return an atomic vector.

Comment: I see, thanks. I am not familiar with CO2 specifically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you don't have to modify your function. Just do this

```
CO2 %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  mutate(
    conc2 = conc^2,
    across(c(Treatment), one_hot)$Treatment # see here
  )
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 84 x 7
   Plant Type   Treatment   conc uptake   conc2 Isnonchilled
   <ord> <fct>  <fct>      <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>        <int>
 1 Qn1   Quebec nonchilled    95   16      9025            1
 2 Qn1   Quebec nonchilled   175   30.4   30625            1
 3 Qn1   Quebec nonchilled   250   34.8   62500            1
 4 Qn1   Quebec nonchilled   350   37.2  122500            1
 5 Qn1   Quebec nonchilled   500   35.3  250000            1
 6 Qn1   Quebec nonchilled   675   39.2  455625            1
 7 Qn1   Quebec nonchilled  1000   39.7 1000000            1
 8 Qn2   Quebec nonchilled    95   13.6    9025            1
 9 Qn2   Quebec nonchilled   175   27.3   30625            1
10 Qn2   Quebec nonchilled   250   37.1   62500            1
# ... with 74 more rows
```

For mutation across many columns,

```
CO2 %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  mutate(
    conc2 = conc^2,
    bind_cols(as.list(across(starts_with("T"), one_hot)))
  )
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 84 x 8
   Plant Type   Treatment   conc uptake   conc2 IsQuebec Isnonchilled
   <ord> <fct>  <fct>      <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>    <int>        <int>
 1 Qn1   Quebec nonchilled    95   16      9025        1            1
 2 Qn1   Quebec nonchilled   175   30.4   30625        1            1
 3 Qn1   Quebec nonchilled   250   34.8   62500        1            1
 4 Qn1   Quebec nonchilled   350   37.2  122500        1            1
 5 Qn1   Quebec nonchilled   500   35.3  250000        1            1
 6 Qn1   Quebec nonchilled   675   39.2  455625        1            1
 7 Qn1   Quebec nonchilled  1000   39.7 1000000        1            1
 8 Qn2   Quebec nonchilled    95   13.6    9025        1            1
 9 Qn2   Quebec nonchilled   175   27.3   30625        1            1
10 Qn2   Quebec nonchilled   250   37.1   62500        1            1
# ... with 74 more rows
```

Comment: Beautiful!!!  Works with n columns returned as well in the `bind_cols` version.

Answer (score 1):

The output of the function is a data.frame. Inside the function, I am using the `pull` function to get the vector.

```
library(textshape)
library(dplyr)

one_hot <- function(x, drop.jth = TRUE, keep.na = TRUE, prefix = "Is", ...) {
  y <- tibble::as_tibble(textshape::mtabulate(x))
  if (keep.na) y[is.na(x), ] <- NA
  if(drop.jth) y <- y[1:(ncol(y) - 1)]
  colnames(y) <- paste0(prefix, colnames(y))
  y %>% pull(1) # you need to transform the df to a vector
}

CO2 %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  mutate(
    conc2 = conc^2,
    across(c(Treatment), one_hot)
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Using your original function and `purrr::map`, you could generate a list of columns then bind them back to your original dataframe.

```
purrr::map(c('Treatment','Type'), ~one_hot(CO2[[.x]])) %>%
  bind_cols(CO2)
```

```
# A tibble: 84 x 7
   Isnonchilled IsQuebec Plant Type   Treatment   conc uptake
          <int>    <int> <ord> <fct>  <fct>      <dbl>  <dbl>
 1            1        1 Qn1   Quebec nonchilled    95   16  
 2            1        1 Qn1   Quebec nonchilled   175   30.4
 3            1        1 Qn1   Quebec nonchilled   250   34.8
 4            1        1 Qn1   Quebec nonchilled   350   37.2
 5            1        1 Qn1   Quebec nonchilled   500   35.3
```